# Get Documents from specific folder from specific library using Search api CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I need to get documents from specific folder from siteassets and .aspx files from Pages library.
I tried:

**$quertText="contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary"**
    this query retrieving all documents from the documentlibrary and also from siteassets.But how to get  documents from specific folder from site assets
And same for pages library from specific folder i should get .aspx files .How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the Path parameter.

```
path:"https://siteURL.com/pages/foldername/*"
```

This [previously asked question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110241/multiple-relative-path-in-sharepoint-2013-cswps) has a good break down on the various usages.

Comment: but im doing Search for entire tenant .Is it possible to query for specific folder in  specific library without passing specifically folder path? I know this  maybe a wrong question..but im new to Search and confirming  is there any other way in Search API without specifying exact folder url. Kindly clarify.